# Ubuntu can't read SD Card

Tags: drivers, usb, sd-card, card-reader

I have Ubuntu 20.04 LTS installed, but apparently it can't read the SD Card although I have a reader in my laptop.
I've tried running `lsusb` and it shows the card reader, but `sudo lsblk -f` doesnt show the card itself and based on `sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` apparently there is a problem initialising the card, if thats correct how to fix this?

```
ubai@ubai-msi:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 232b:5e20 Pantum M6550NW series
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1770:ff00 MSI EPF USB MSI EPF USB
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 046d:c534 Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


ubai@ubai-msi:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL      UUID                                 FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/canonical-livepatch/95
loop1  squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/code/49
loop2  squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/core18/1932
loop3  squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/core18/1880
loop4  squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/core/10185
loop5  squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/kde-frameworks-5-qt-5-14-core18/4
loop6  squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/36
loop7  squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/code/50
loop8  squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/pycharm-professional/223
loop9  squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/snap-store/498
loop10 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/terminal-parrot/59
loop11 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/snapd/10492
loop12 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/145
loop13 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/core/10444
loop14 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/snapd/10238
loop15 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/60
loop16 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/pycharm-professional/226
loop17 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/mailspring/488
loop18 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/snap-store/467
loop19 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1513
loop20 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1514
loop21 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/zenkit/12
loop22 squashfs                                                       0   100% /snap/zenkit/10
sda                                                                            
├─sda1 vfat                0827-09A2                             222.7M     5% /boot/efi
├─sda2 swap                cdc83f2f-af60-4d25-a46e-a612cf029b79                [SWAP]
└─sda3 ext4                60af2389-20f3-45b6-abc3-a390bd9c49f3   38.3G    56% /
sdb                                                                            
├─sdb1 ext4     Data       9b39dae5-33fb-4d13-8f78-cc789443f56f  449.6G    10% /media/ubai/Data
├─sdb2 ntfs     BIOS_RVY   C2127CCF127CC9C5                                    
└─sdb3 ntfs     Windows 10 6365245473E948FC

ubai@ubai-msi:~$ sudo dmesg | tail -n 50
[77435.779623] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
[77437.975971] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 9 using xhci_hcd
[77438.124390] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1908, idProduct=0226, bcdDevice= 1.11
[77438.124395] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[77438.140650] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[77438.140781] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[77438.140876] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[77438.142505] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[77439.152634] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Mass-Storage     1.11 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[77439.153269] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[77441.386054] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[77449.493326] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 9
[77449.503765] scsi 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device
[77449.847858] usb 1-2: new full-speed USB device number 10 using xhci_hcd
[77517.358828] usb 1-2: new high-speed USB device number 11 using xhci_hcd
[77517.507273] usb 1-2: New USB device found, idVendor=1908, idProduct=0226, bcdDevice= 1.11
[77517.507278] usb 1-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[77517.509547] usb-storage 1-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[77517.509939] scsi host6: usb-storage 1-2:1.0
[77518.511669] scsi 6:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Mass-Storage     1.11 PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
[77518.512364] sd 6:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
[77520.744522] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
[77534.323077] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 11
[77534.330437] scsi 6:0:0:0: rejecting I/O to dead device
[77599.149806] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[77602.285715] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[77605.421723] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[77616.989137] usb 1-1: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[77617.140006] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c534, bcdDevice=29.01
[77617.140012] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[77617.140015] usb 1-1: Product: USB Receiver
[77617.140019] usb 1-1: Manufacturer: Logitech
[77617.144633] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C534.0007: hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input0
[77617.204435] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C534.0008: hiddev0,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1
[77617.262862] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C534.0008: device of type eQUAD nano Lite (0x0a) connected on slot 1
[77617.264858] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C534.0008: device of type eQUAD nano Lite (0x0a) connected on slot 2
[77617.278123] input: Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0008/0003:046D:4023.0009/input/input40
[77617.278371] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4023.0009: input,hidraw2: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech Wireless Keyboard PID:4023] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1:1
[77617.294832] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4054.000A: HID++ 4.5 device connected.
[77617.350912] input: Logitech Wireless Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.1/0003:046D:C534.0008/0003:046D:4054.000A/input/input41
[77617.351057] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4054.000A: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Mouse             [Logitech Wireless Mouse] on usb-0000:00:14.0-1/input1:2
[77735.276028] mmc0: error -123 whilst initialising SD card
[77750.859312] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[77753.995337] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[77757.131232] mmc0: error -110 whilst initialising SD card
[78079.091102] ACPI Error: No handler for Region [VRTC] (000000005ab8a5c9) [SystemCMOS] (20190816/evregion-127)
[78079.091117] ACPI Error: Region SystemCMOS (ID=5) has no handler (20190816/exfldio-261)
[78079.091137] No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_Q9A]
[78079.091140] No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q9A]
[78079.091144] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.EC._Q9A due to previous error (AE_NOT_EXIST) (20190816/psparse-529)
```

Comment: Is this an SDHC or SDXC card? There are occasionally issues when reading the higher capacity cards from some manufacturers.

Comment: @Matigo I think it's SDHC (I see HC written on the card).

Comment: I found this question because my "Realtek USB 3.0 Card Reader" (`ID 0bda:0309 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. USB3.0-CRW`) was not listed at all when running `lsusb` on my Raspberry Pi 4 *Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS*. Turns out there was some problem when attaching the reader to a USB hub. Instead, attaching it to a USB 2.0 port directly on the Raspberry Pi, immediately worked and automatically setup `/dev/sdXY` device files for each partition on the SD card inserted in the card reader.

Answer (score 0):

There are some instances where SDHC and SDXC cards cannot be read properly, but there is a little bit of a hack that has worked for me a couple of times in the past. The one problem is that this solution usually limits the speed of copying to 1/8th the advertised transfer speed. So a really good SDXC card might be limited to just 10MB/sec.

That said, you can give this a try if you're interested:

1. Open terminal
2. Create a file with: `sudo /etc/modprobe.d/sdcard.conf`
3. Paste this into the file: `options sdhci debug_quirks2=0x2`
4. Save the file

Once this is done, we'll need to remove and probe some modules:

```
sudo rmmod sdhci_acpi sdhci_pci sdhci
sudo modprobe sdhci; sudo modprobe sdhci_acpi; sudo modprobe sdhci_pci
```

Then, to save the config and make it active:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

I have done this successfully with Lenovo, Dell, and Acer notebooks over the years. The only problem, as I mentioned earlier, is that you will not get the full speed of the SD card.

Hope this helps you as well

Comment: Thanks for your reply, The problem is still present, I noticed the the modules werent loaded when i tried to remove them, plus now ` sudo dmesg | tail -n 50` returns                          [83083.944122] sdhci: Secure Digital Host Controller Interface driver
[83083.944122] sdhci: Copyright(c) Pierre Ossman
which is different from before